# $(id).val(option) don't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I have the following codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjVOmL, it works on firefox and in chrome, but not on safari.

Does `$('#make').val(make);` or `document.getElementById("make").value = make;` don't work on safari?

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry. I was so nervious because I searched for a couple of hours with no success. Already fixed.

Comment: You should include these in your question. Codepen can disappear tomorrow and then your question and potential answers won't be useful to anyone else.